# Cant start cassandra on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax, ec2-ami

Hello I installed cassandra on Ec2 instance and configured yaml file and topology settings but when i start the service (first time) it is throwing the below error. Can anyone tell me the fix? Many thanks

```
Fail setting `ulimit '-p' '8'`: /etc/init.d/dse: line 430: ulimit: pipe size: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
```

Pre flight check result:

```
ERROR   vm.max_map_count is set to 65530.
ERROR   Suggested value is 131072.
ERROR   Kernel State check did not complete successfully.

ERROR   12 missing limits found:
ERROR           * soft nofile 32768
ERROR           * hard nofile 32768
ERROR           root soft nofile 32768
ERROR           root hard nofile 32768
ERROR           * soft memlock unlimited
ERROR           * hard memlock unlimited
ERROR           root soft memlock unlimited
ERROR           root hard memlock unlimited
ERROR           * soft as unlimited
ERROR           * hard as unlimited
ERROR           root soft as unlimited
ERROR           root hard as unlimited
ERROR   Limits check did not complete successfully.

INFO    '/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf' does not exist. Shouldn't need this fix.
```

Comment: Try running the pre-flight check tool, located in /usr/share/dse/tools

Comment: I have added the errors. Sorry I am not aware of these problems. Is there anything you could tell me on these issues. I am trying to find individually fix.

Comment: Follow these steps: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html